# How do I compare a text file with a list of words and whichever word is not in the list I have to write down in a third file (in C)

Tags: c, file, txt

I think the title sums it up. I am pretty new in C programming and this is my first assignment with files. My input files are as follows:
(The one to check)

> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

(The "list" file)

> the The
>
> quick Quick
>
> jumps Jumps

My output file:

> |brown|
>
> |fox|
>
> |jumps|
>
> |over|
>
> |the|
>
> |lazy|
>
> |dog|

Problems with the behaviour of my program which I am unsure how to fix: It does check words but only if they are in order, as soon as it runs into a word that is in the list, it just prints the rest of the file.
Do I need to implement a linked list, the contents of which are the words from the list? I do know what it is but I failed to implement it in this program.
Here is what I have so far(without my failed attempt at a linked list):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int CheckMissing(FILE* dictionary, char dif[30]) {
char miss[30];
while (fscanf(dictionary, "%s", miss) != EOF) {

    if (strcmp(dif, miss) == 0) {

        return 1;
    }
}


return 0;

}

int main()
{
FILE* text;
FILE* dictionary;
FILE* diff;
char path_t[1000];
char path_d[1000];
char path_diff[1000];
char word[30];
printf("Path of file to check: ");
scanf("%s", path_t);
/*FILE TO READ*/
text = fopen(path_t, "r");
if (text == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR OPENING TEXT FILE!");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Path of file to check from: ");
scanf("%s", path_d);
/*LIST OF WORDS*/
dictionary = fopen(path_d, "r");
if (dictionary == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR OPENING DICTIONARY!");
}
printf("Path of file to write differences: ");
scanf("%s", path_diff);
/*THE NEW FILE*/
diff = fopen(path_diff, "a");
if (diff == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR OPENING FILE TO WRITE!");
    exit(1);
}


/*Get word and send to function*/
while (fscanf(text, "%s", word) != EOF) {
    if (CheckMissing(dictionary, word) == 1) {

    }
    else {
        //The word is printed on another file
        fprintf(diff, "|%s|\n", word);
    }

}
fclose(text);
fclose(dictionary);
fclose(diff);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you never rewind your `dictionary` before moving to each subsequent word, this is doomed from the start. `CheckMissing` just continues off from wherever the last scan stopped (including EOF) and therefore, the first word that is *not* in your dictionary will exhibit as all subsequent words thereafter aren't either.

Comment: Since you are new to C programming I think you should stop asking the user for input. Just don't do it. Write a main file which has fixed file names and debug your attempt at a solution with that. You can make things interactive later.

Comment: @WhozCraig ,  This makes so much sense. But where should i put rewind() ? I just put it in 'CheckMissing' and the program couldn't finish. The created file is blank?

Comment: Write a `bool CheckMissing(const char *filename, const char *word);` function. You supply the filename to the function, so the file will be opened again every time.

Comment: @CostantinoGrana , I know that it is better off fixed but I am writing this as per an assignment requirment. It's just some extra code which can't possibly break it, I think. Trying to pin down the algorithm and I'm basically done :)

Comment: @CostantinoGrana I tried writing it, included the header file and it throws an exception when I try strcmp()

Why?

Answer (score 0):

In C when you open a file, it will assign a pointer for you to iterate over it. In your case, you are opening it and never reseting this pointer and when it finishes the file, it doesn't check any words more.

If you want to reset this file pointer you can close the file and open it again. But its not an efficient solution. Better way is using fseek() function. Which takes 3 argument

```
int fseek(FILE *stream, long int offset, int whence)
```

To reset it to the start of file you need to use:

```
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET)
```

Only thing you need to change in your code is CheckMissing function. For 1 or 0 results you need to reset File Pointers position. I added also a print line for you, you can see how this pointer works.

Below is fixed code:

```
int CheckMissing(FILE* dictionary, char dif[30]) {
char miss[30];
while (fscanf(dictionary, "%s", miss) != EOF) {
    printf("checking %s and %s\n", miss, dif);
    if (strcmp(dif, miss) == 0) {
        fseek(dictionary, 0, SEEK_SET);
        return 1;
    }
}
fseek(dictionary, 0, SEEK_SET);

return 0;

}
```

For further resource you can check:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fseek.htm

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out, your logic was sound, but you must restart from the beginning of the dictionary file every time.

I suggest that you fix a bunch of other stuff in your program, in order to avoid other common mistakes.

The full program is at the end, but here you have the various pieces:

```
int CheckMissing(FILE* dictionary, const char *dif) 
{
    rewind(dictionary); // <-- This was the key element missing
    char miss[30];
    while (fscanf(dictionary, "%29s", miss) == 1) {
        if (strcmp(dif, miss) == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Here I just added the already mentioned "start from beginning every time". Moreover, I suggest that you really understand that in C you cannot have arrays as function parameters, and that when you write `char dif[30]`, `dif` is a pointer to char. Moreover use const as much as possible!
Then when you scan in a buffer always limit the maximum amount of characters that can be read (the `%29s` instead of just `%s`).
The `fscanf()` function returns the number of fields correctly read, so it's more general to test if the result matches the number of fields to be read, instead of `EOF`. In this case it's the same thing, but as soon as you try to read numbers it will make a huge difference.
Finally I inverted the output, since in my understanding a `CheckMissing` should return "true" if the word is missing.

Then split your `main()` in functions:

```
void OutputWordsNotInList(FILE *text, FILE *dictionary, FILE *diff)
{
    /*Get word and send to function*/
    char word[30];
    while (fscanf(text, "%29s", word) == 1) {
        if (CheckMissing(dictionary, word)) {
            //The word is printed on another file
            fprintf(diff, "|%s|\n", word);
        }
    }
}
```

Not much to say here, but the fact that the `if` statement becomes cleaner with the inverted logic. Of course I limit the maximum characters to be read also here and check for 1 instead of `!= EOF`.

Then **don't copy and paste**! This will lead to inconsistencies. In the second check you missed an `exit(1)`. Make a function for that.

```
FILE *fopen_ExitOnFail(const char *filename, const char *mode, const char *error_message)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, mode);
    if (f == NULL) {
        puts(error_message);
        exit(1);
    }
    return f;
}
```

In the `main()` file **don't ask user input during development**. This will force you to type the input over and over again and make you walk away from debugging, which should be what you do most of the time.
I just made a conditional compilation block that can be activated when the rest is ok:

```
//#define INTERACTIVE

int main(void)
{
    char path_t[1000] = "input.txt";
    char path_d[1000] = "dictionary.txt";
    char path_diff[1000] = "output.txt";

#ifdef INTERACTIVE
    printf("Path of file to check: ");
    scanf("%999s", path_t);
    printf("Path of file to check from: ");
    scanf("%999s", path_d);
    printf("Path of file to write differences: ");
    scanf("%999s", path_diff);
#endif // INTERACTIVE

    /*FILE TO READ*/
    FILE *text = fopen_ExitOnFail(path_t, "r", "ERROR OPENING TEXT FILE!");
    /*LIST OF WORDS*/
    FILE *dictionary = fopen_ExitOnFail(path_d, "r", "ERROR OPENING DICTIONARY!");
    /*THE NEW FILE*/
    FILE *diff = fopen_ExitOnFail(path_diff, "w", "ERROR OPENING FILE TO WRITE!"); // <-- I changed this to "w", to ease debugging.

    OutputWordsNotInList(text, dictionary, diff);
    
    fclose(text);
    fclose(dictionary);
    fclose(diff);

    return 0;
}
```

The full code is here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int CheckMissing(FILE* dictionary, const char *dif) 
{
    rewind(dictionary);
    char miss[30];
    while (fscanf(dictionary, "%29s", miss) == 1) {
        if (strcmp(dif, miss) == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void OutputWordsNotInList(FILE *text, FILE *dictionary, FILE *diff)
{
    /*Get word and send to function*/
    char word[30];
    while (fscanf(text, "%29s", word) == 1) {
        if (CheckMissing(dictionary, word)) {
            //The word is printed on another file
            fprintf(diff, "|%s|\n", word);
        }
    }
}

FILE *fopen_ExitOnFail(const char *filename, const char *mode, const char *error_message)
{
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, mode);
    if (f == NULL) {
        puts(error_message);
        exit(1);
    }
    return f;
}

//#define INTERACTIVE

int main(void)
{
    char path_t[1000] = "input.txt";
    char path_d[1000] = "dictionary.txt";
    char path_diff[1000] = "output.txt";

#ifdef INTERACTIVE
    printf("Path of file to check: ");
    scanf("%999s", path_t);
    printf("Path of file to check from: ");
    scanf("%999s", path_d);
    printf("Path of file to write differences: ");
    scanf("%999s", path_diff);
#endif // INTERACTIVE

    /*FILE TO READ*/
    FILE *text = fopen_ExitOnFail(path_t, "r", "ERROR OPENING TEXT FILE!");
    /*LIST OF WORDS*/
    FILE *dictionary = fopen_ExitOnFail(path_d, "r", "ERROR OPENING DICTIONARY!");
    /*THE NEW FILE*/
    FILE *diff = fopen_ExitOnFail(path_diff, "w", "ERROR OPENING FILE TO WRITE!"); // <-- I changed this to "w", to ease debugging.

    OutputWordsNotInList(text, dictionary, diff);
    
    fclose(text);
    fclose(dictionary);
    fclose(diff);

    return 0;
}
```